# How to get approx 500request/sec in HAProxy and Tomcat7 with Apache

Tags: haproxy, scalability, tomcat7

I have 4 intstances of Tomcat 7 server and deployed my web App on all the instances. I am using HAProxy load balancer for load balancing. In front end I am using Apche2 web server and behind Tomcat 7. HAproxy is redirecting a;; the request towards different tomcat instance. Now the throughput is 60request/secs. I would like to get 200-500 requests/sec. What all are the configuration parameters in HAProxy need to set to achieve this. I am using Linux CentOs 6.3 version.

All the instances of Tomcat and Apache are running on the same Machine.

Thanks

Comment: I would investigate in this field: "All the instances of Tomcat and Apache are running on the same Machine."

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't going to get many answers here.  This isn't an easy question to answer, and would be entirely dependent on your hardware, your application, etc.

That said, you should benchmark each piece of your infrastructure and find out where the bottleneck is.  Until you know if it's apache, tomcat, haproxy, a database backend if there is one.

Until you know where the problem is, you can't really fix it.